# WP Query—Relationship between two custom post types and their fields

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields and Genesis and trying to modify a template to reflect a relationship between two custom post types (using their associated custom fields.) In this case, I have custom post types for "Staff" and "Reports", and for staff, I have the custom fields "first_name" and "last_name"; and associated with the "Reports" CPT, I also have two custom fields "primary_contact" and "associated_contact"— and in the "single-staff.php" template, I'd like to render a list of any associated reports in the sidebar that would include entries (post titles) for which **that staff member** is defined as *either* a "primary_contact" or an "associated_contact."

Thus, for example, if I've created "Tom Jones" as a staff member (an instance of the "Staff" post type), is it possible for me to define a query that outputs a list of reports for which "Tom Jones" is defined as a "primary_contact" and/or "associated_contact" in any instances of the "Reports" custom post type? I'm including a (very) rough concept for this query below:

```
$args = array(
'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'post_type' => 'reports',
            'meta_key' => 'primary_contact',
            'meta_value' => '$this.full_name',
        ),
        array(
            'post_type' => 'reports',
            'meta_key' => 'associated_contact',
            'meta_value' => '$this.full_name',
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Please let me know if the question is not sufficiently clear-- and thank you for any insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this but it SHOULD work.  You'll want to put it in the single-staff.php.  You'll have to add the details (actual query, post types, etc).

```
$reports = get_posts(array(
                            'post_type' => 'reports',  //use actual post type
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                'relation' => 'or',
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'primary_contact', // name of custom field
                                    'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"', // matches exaclty "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                )
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'associated_contact', // name of custom field
                                    'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"', // matches exaclty "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                )
                            )
                        ));

                        ?>
                        <?php if( $reports ): ?>
                            <ul>
                            <?php foreach( $reports as $report ): ?>
                                <li>
                                    <?php echo get_the_title( $doctor->ID ); ?>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thank you very much for the feedback @rudtek-- would you explain how/why you're using `get_the_ID()` to match the name of the relevant staff member? And the `echo` line would be `get_the_title( $report->ID);` no?

Comment: oops yep.  $report -> ID.    I don't know your exact setup with fields etc, but (relationship, post object etc)  so you may have to change a bit.  See this example:  https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/

Comment: Ok thanks-- in my case the main fields are all post objects, e.g. "primary_contact" and "associated_contact" are defined in ACF as post objects with the relevant filter applied, just as with the "reports" CPT, the related contacts are defined as post objects with the filter "staff" applied. All are configured to return post IDs, so I'm thinking it will work with your approach?

Comment: should.  I'm on pins and needles waiting to find out!

Comment: Ha ok, I'll try and report back!

Comment: Just a note to follow up-- with some slight variations, this ended up working pefectly! Thanks @rudtek

Answer (score 1):

Another option: there's an ACF add-on called [Bidirectional Relationships](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/bidirectional-relationships/) that may simplify this for you. You define relationships in ACF, and then when you're editing either post type, you'll see a box that lets you search or select from a list the related content. You can then use that info in your templates however you like.